# logic apps - how to link to a run

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a dashboard in Power BI that shows me all the runs that have failed from Logic Apps, incl their runID. Currently I need to copy and paste that runID into the Logic App Runs UI to filter and then click on it to see the Run detail and find out where it failed.

When I click on a run, the runID is not added to the URL, it's loaded via some javascript. How do I generate a URL that will link to a specific run of a logic app instance?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I was looking for the same thing and came across your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround for this is to add logging/tracked properties etc so that you will get which action failed directly with the runid, it's as close you will get for now I think.

[Edit] found a solution here:

https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2018/12/08/navigate-directly-to-the-logic-apps-run-details/

Answer (score 0):

For Logic Apps (Standard) there is currently no deeplink available yet. Though Microsoft has added this to their backlog.

See: https://githubmemory.com/repo/Azure/logicapps/issues/358

**Edit**
Not official, but I figured a way to navigate directly to a Logic App (Standard) workflow. It is possible that a page refresh is needed after navigation though.

Url: [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/WorkflowMonitorBlade/id/%2Fsubscriptions%2F**subscription-id**%2FresourceGroups%2F**resource-group**%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Web%2Fsites%2F**logic-app-name**%2Fworkflows%2F**workflow-name**/location/**location**/resourceId/%2Fworkflows%2F**workflow-name**%2Fruns%**run-id**/runProperties~/%7B%22waitEndTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22workflow%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22trigger%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22inputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22outputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22originHistoryName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22outputs%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22response%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22outputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22code%22%3A%22%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D/isReadOnly~/false](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/WorkflowMonitorBlade/id/%2Fsubscriptions%2F**subscription-id**%2FresourceGroups%2F**resource-group**%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Web%2Fsites%2F**logic-app-name**%2Fworkflows%2F**workflow-name**/location/**location**/resourceId/%2Fworkflows%2F**workflow-name**%2Fruns%**run-id**/runProperties%7E/%7B%22waitEndTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22workflow%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22trigger%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22inputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22outputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22originHistoryName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22outputs%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22response%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22outputsLink%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contentSize%22%3A0%7D%2C%22startTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%22%22%2C%22correlation%22%3A%7B%22clientTrackingId%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22code%22%3A%22%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D/isReadOnly%7E/false)